# Should chrome extensions have access to Tabs content (other websites)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to identify and block JS files/events that are not part of your domain?

Like assume, if I'm writing a extension for chrome and I put following code in my JS

```
$('div').on('click', function(){ alert("yup"); });
```

is there a way for a website to handle this case?

#### Edit 1:

After discussion with @Clive, I realized that all extension/application should run in sandbox and should not be able to access events/elements outside the scope.

#### Case

A chrome extension have a keypress event on `input[type=text]` and `input[type=password]`. Now this extension runs in background, so there JS files are always available. Hence if you open facebook and login to your account, this extension will capture data and can send it to its server.

#### My Case

Two user was getting `alert messages` multiple times. Initially we thought its a part of our code and checked all JS files. But then realized, both user had same extension and so we diagnosed that extension's JS file and found alert in it. Now we were lucky, no damage was done, but it still posses a possible security  threat.

Comment: You want your website to be able to disable a feature the user has intentionally installed in their own browser? That can't be possible in any good browser I would've thought, things like ad blockers simply wouldn't be able to work. It's up to users what extensions they want to install and use, not you

Comment: Just assume, tomorrow I create a facebook extension and provide some great performance/features. Now user will install it to get facebook notification, But silently, I'm logging all keystrokes for Input box and sending it to my personal account. Now if user opens his bank account in same window in another tab, I'll get all that information. Isn't this threat?

Comment: Do you think allowing a website to control a user's machine, beyond the intended purpose of displaying a web page, is less of a threat? Extensions have security, they can't just grab your bank details by default. If you install random extensions without checking that they're safe first, and give them inappropriate access to your browser, that's kind of on you

Comment: Browsers are link sandbox, so I cannot control user's machine. All I could try to do is control the browser, which also is wrong. But should extensions/application have access outside their domain? 

And I have faced similar issue and hence asked it on stack. A user of my website had installed an extension where coder had written alert message on ajax complete and this also affected my ajax requests. Not much harm done in my case but still people can code to do lot more damage so wanted to ask if this even exists?

Comment: I don't know 100%, but my instinct would be that no, your website can't override the user's own intent to use an extension. Interesting question actually

Comment: Thanks. and i dont want to override anything. Question is should extensions also be sandbox?  Should there JS files have access to entire browser or just to their domain?

Comment: I believe you select those options when you install/configure the extension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91916/discussion-between-rajesh-and-clive).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

Chrome extensions run their code in a separate space from your site's code, so they don't interact at all. The best you could do is prevent DOM edits. Luckily chrome extensions already run in a sandbox and have to explicitly ask for permissions for the domains that they inject code in and those domains are all listed when you install an extension. The only other way for extensions to interact with a page is through the `activeTab` permission which is a one time allowance on a [specific user action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab). If you are using an extension that you think is malicious, you can always just read the code since JS is naturally open source. It really all boils down to a matter of trust. Installing something is explicitly trusting that thing to not mess up your stuff. This applies to all programs. If you don't trust an extension, then don't install it. A sandbox can only prevent so much while still letting extensions do something.